# What's the optimal way to query data using another table column as a between filter

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

sorry for the ambiguous question title. I don't know what's it called.

The thing is let's say I've a `order` table storing `uid` , `order_id` and `ip` looks like this

```
| uid   | order_id |    ip
| 10000 |    1     | 2098957412
| 10001 |    2     | 2869229574
| 10000 |    3     |  825358912
```

and another `ip` table storing `ip_from` , `ip_to` and `country_code`

```
| ip_from    |   ip_to     |  country_code
| 10000      |   200000    |      GM
| 825358910  |  925358912  |      VN
| 2098957412 | 2198957412  |      FR
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
select order.uid, order.order_id, order.ip, ip.country_code
from order
left join ip
on  order.ip >= ip.ip_from
and order.ip <= ip.ip_to
```

to have a result like this

```
| uid   | order_id |    ip       | country_code
| 10000 |    1     | 2098957412  |     FR
| 10001 |    2     | 2869229574  |    null
| 10000 |    3     |  825358912  |     VN
```

What's the optimal query to having such a result?

Comment: Is this made up data or is it real? If this data is real, shouldn't there be a `BETWEEN` somewhere in the query? Note: I am not a networking person! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: @Vérace thanks, the logic is real actually. But I think between is equivalent to `>=` and `<=` right ? Don't know which one would processed faster anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name normally how the IP address should be stored?

Comment: Is `ip` an "IP-address"?

Comment: @RickJames yes ipv4

Answer (score 0):

> What's the optimal query to having such a result?

**Simple.**

Create proper indices (`order(ip)` and `ip(ip_from,ip_to)`).

**Complex.**

Create a field of LINESTRING type from `ip_from` to `ip_to`. Create spatial index (RTree) by it. Use `MBRContains` for filtering.

---

From the other side - the ranges `(ip_from,ip_to)` must be NON-overlapped.

If it is true, then you'll obtain the result with simple

```
select order.uid, 
       order.order_id, 
       order.ip, 
       ( SELECT ip.country_code
         FROM ip
         WHERE ip.ip_from <= order.ip
         ORDER BY ip.ip_from DESC
         LIMIT 1 ) country_code
from order
```

Indices `ip(ip_from)` and `order(ip)` (or even covering index `ip(ip_from, country_code)`) is enough for this query.

Comment: @Peem You will use GEOMETRY and its RTree index for to determine the segment on which the point lies. It is more fast than use common BETWEEN and BTree index.

Comment: @Peem Shown correlated subquery uses direct search for the constant by index and must be fast. You may create covering index `(ip_from, country_code)` for to increase the speed one more.

Comment: @Peem It's better to read the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html

Comment: The best any BTree index can do is to scan an average of half the `ip` table.  How many rows in each table?